# how to use FOSCommentBundle

Tags: symfony

Im new to symfony3 and I need a bit of help,I have a timeline page that contains posts and every post has a comment field so in order to do that I've installed the FOSCommentBundle following all the steps in this documentation https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md and then I integrated it with the FOSUserBundle, and I did the following changes in the async.html.twig file :

```
<div id="fos_comment_thread">#comments</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // thread id
    var fos_comment_thread_id = 'pub';

    // api base url to use for initial requests
    var fos_comment_thread_api_base_url = 'localhost/Outdoors5/web/app_dev.php/threads';

    // Snippet for asynchronously loading the comments
    (function() {
        var fos_comment_script = document.createElement('script');
        fos_comment_script.async = true;
        fos_comment_script.src = '{{ asset('bundles/foscomment/js/comments.js') }}';
        fos_comment_script.type = 'text/javascript';

        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(fos_comment_script);
    })();
</script>
```

but in the end I got very confused on how I use this ,I passed hours trying to understand and searching for tuto, but no luck.
this is my view

```
           <section id="timeline">


                {% for publication in publications %}

<div id="result"></div>
                    <div class="page-content page-app page-profil " >
                            <div class="profil-content">
                                <div class="row">
                                        <div class="row">

                                                <div class="item item-comment">
                                                    <div class="user">
                                                        <h5 class="name">{{ publication.idProfil.nom }}</h5>
                                                        <div class="clearfix">
                                                            <p class="time">{% if publication.dateCreation %}{{ publication.dateCreation|date('Y-m-d') }}{% endif %}</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="comment">
                                                            <p class="c-primary m-b-0"><strong>{{ publication.texte }}</strong></p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="more">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-sm-4 like">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Like
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-4 more-comments">
                                                                <div class="comment-number">
                                                                    <i class="icon-bubble"></i> Comments<span class="pull-right badge badge-dark">3</span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-4 more-share">
                                                                <i class="icon-share"></i> Share
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row comments">
                                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                                <ul>
                                                                    <li class="clearfix">
                                                                        <div class="clearfix">
                                                                            <div class="info">
                                                                                <div class="name"><strong class="primary-font"></strong></div>
                                                                                <div class="date"></div>
                                                                            </div>

                                                                            <p>

                                                                                comment 1 

                                                                            </p>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                    <li></li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row share">
                                                            <div class="share-facebook">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="share-twitter">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="share-google">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                {% endfor %}
            </section>
```

Could you point me to the right direction?
 thank you

Comment: Have you been able to make FOSCommentBundle work following the suggestions from my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to modify `async.html.twig`. You just need to add the following code in your twig view:

```
{% include 'FOSCommentBundle:Thread:async.html.twig' with {'id': 'foo'} %}
```

To sum up, after doing the following steps:

- [Step 1: Setting up the bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md#step-1-setting-up-the-bundle)
- [Step 2: Create your Comment and Thread classes](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-create_your_comment_and_thread_classes.md#step-2-create-your-comment-and-thread-classes)
- [Step 3: Import FOSCommentBundle routing](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-importing_foscommentbundle_routing.md#step-3-import-foscommentbundle-routing)
- [Step 4: Enable comments on a page](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/4-enable_comments_on_a_page.md#step-4-enable-comments-on-a-page)

For the FOSUserBundle integration you just have to extend the `Comment` class as explained in [Step 6: Integration with FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/6-integration_with_fosuserbundle.md#b-extend-the-comment-class)